# How can I Increase the dimensions of tensor in java?

Tags: java, pytorch

I have (pytorch) tensor object in java.
(https://pytorch.org/javadoc/org/pytorch/Tensor.html)
The shape of tensor is (3 x H x W) where 3 represent (R,G,B) each.

The tensor is actually gained from bitmap image (shape = H x W)
by performing the following command, outputting (3 x H x W) which is in the TensorImageUtils (https://pytorch.org/docs/1.3.1/org/pytorch/TensorImageUtils.html)

```
final Tensor inputTensor = TensorImageUtils.bitmapToFloat32Tensor(bitmap,
TensorImageUtils.TORCHVISION_NORM_MEAN_RGB, TensorImageUtils.TORCHVISION_NORM_STD_RGB);
```

but I need (1 x 3 x H x W) tensor, not (3 x H x W) in java.
In python, that can be performed by

```
torch.unsqueeze(x, 0) # adding one dimension in x
```

where x is (3 x H x W) tensor (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html)

in java, I think there is no unsqueeze command, how can i expand the dimension of tensor in java?

Comment: This kind of operation is probably only available via the C++ API, but we can now easily access it from Java with the JavaCPP Presets for PyTorch: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/pytorch